# count++ not working in an if statement

Tags: java

Trying to display an error message so that when the user enters the pin incorrect three times its will display the error message "account blocked". Why is pinAttempts++ not adding 1 each time the incorrect pin is entered?

```
try {
    int pinAttempts = 0;
    int pin = Integer.parseInt(enterPinJTextField.getText());
    if (pinAttempts == 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(popupFrame, "Account blocked!");
    }
    if (pin != PIN) {
        pinAttempts++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(popupFrame, "Please enter correct pin!");
    } else {
        BankAccount application = new BankAccount();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(popupFrame, "Please enter a number");
}
```

Comment: 1.)dont make pinAttempts=0; into the try{} if you call it every time the user press enter! 2.)and if(pinAttempts == 3){... put a return; to return back and not do the other code}

Comment: @Kelv if one of the answer worked for you, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you are setting it to `0` again

```
int pinAttempts = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Every time you enter the try statement you set pinAttempts to 0.  This means whatever it was before will be over-written.

You should move `pintAttempts = 0` to somewhere that initialization happens so it only happens once.  Or have it in a method where you can reset the attempt counter for a user.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is pinAttempts++ not adding 1 each time the incorrect pin is
>   entered?

It is don't worry, it is your understanding that is wrong.

You need to realize that you are re-initializing `pinAttempts` to 0 each time you re-enter the `try` block using

`int pinAttempts = 0;` at the beginning.

Declare the variable globally (at the top of you class) instead of declaring it in the `try/catch` block and it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `pinAttempts` is getting initialized again and again with value `0`

Make your `pinAttempts` either static or declare it someplace where it not get initialized again and again , I will do something like this .

```
static int pinAttempts=0;
public boolean isLoginSuccessfull(){

//here do whatever you want to do .

}
```

This login successfull will be called whenever user attempts to login , So `pinAttempts` will not get initialized again ,and as soon as you decide to **unblock** the user make that `pinAttempts` count again to `0`